# projectraster in R cannot complete transformation

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, utm, rgdal

I have a few .tif rasters (ELEV and POP) projected in long/lat, but I would like the CRS and extent to be the same as a shapefile I have (STUDYAREA), for example, my study area lies mostly in UTM16 so I want that to be in the crs for all objects. Also, I would like them all to have a 1000*1000m resolution.

I first make sure that the extent is the same as the shapefile, as I've learned that working with objects with a different extent will give an error.
Here is how I try to reach my goal:

```
create object to adapt other objects extent to (needs to be equal to extent of STUDYAREA)
studyarea <- spTransform(studyarea,CRSobj= "+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84 +units=m + no_defs")
areaextent <- extent(studyarea)
projection <- "+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

elev <- raster("Gtopo30/Gtopo30.TIF")
newelev <- setExtent(elev,areaextent)
elev <- projectRaster(newelev,res=1000,crs=projection)


pop <- raster("griddedpop/gpw.tif")
pop <- setExtent(elev,areaextent,keepres=FALSE)
pop <- projectRaster(pop,crs=projection)
```

But when using the ProjectRaster function, I run into very similar errors for both raster projections:

```
elev <- projectRaster(newelev,res=1000,crs=projection)
Error in projectExtent(from, projto) : cannot do this transformation
In addition: Warning message:
In rgdal::rawTransform(projfrom, projto, nrow(xy), xy[, 1], xy[,  :
704 projected point(s) not finite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an improved version of your code. As you do not provide example data I cannot say if it works better.

```
library(raster)
projection <- "+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
studyarea <- spTransform(studyarea, CRSobj=projection)

# make a template RasterLayer
template <- raster(studyarea, res=1000)

# use the template 
elev <- raster("Gtopo30/Gtopo30.TIF")
elevutm <- projectRaster(elev, template)
```

You can also use projectRaster without a template like this:

```
elevutm2 <- projectRaster(elev, crs=projection, res=1000)
```

But I do not recommend that, as you have less control that way.

Below the same workflow, but with example data and using the `terra` package (the replacement of `raster`)

```
library(terra)
prj <- "+proj=utm +zone=32 +units=m"
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))

sa <- project(v, prj)
tmp <- rast(sa, resolution=1000)
# to get a nicer extent 
ext(tmp) <- floor(ext(r)+5000)

elevation <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
elevprj <- project(elevation, tmp)

plot(elevprj)
lines(sa)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Robert!

It works, yetI am quite surprised that

 `elevutm2 <- projectRaster(elev, crs=projection, res=1000)`   

works, after all, isn't this exactly what I did, except for that the name of the assigned object is not a pre-existing object? My line being

`elev <- projectRaster(newelev,res=1000,crs=projection) `    

with 'elev' being an already existing object to be replaced by this new code.
Why would this make a difference and not have me run into the error?

Comment: I think your mistake is `newelev <- setExtent(elev,  areaextent)`   That would seem to assign a UTM extent to a lonlat raster; creating invalid coordinates (latitude >> 90 or << -90)

Comment: That makes sense! I think in general my trouble is with the following:

When working with projectRaster I have in the past gotten an error when trying to project raster 1 to raster 2 when these are of a different extent. So I try to equal the extent of my rasters before using projectRaster, but this leads to trouble when the rasters are in a different CRS (specifically a UTM vs longlat). 

So I guess what I'm looking for is the most straightforward way to equalize a raster to another one in terms of CRS, extent and resolution?

Comment: When projecting from r1 to r2, the extents are (almost) always different, so that was probably not the real issue. But you can try `projectExtent` and first project an empty raster (with no values) to see where it ends up and adjust that.

Comment: Thanks again Robert!
In this particular case, I would like to crop the 'pop' raster (global population) to the orginal 'studyarea' shapefile before I do the projectRaster. Simply because the whole 'pop' raster is way too large, it would take too much memory.  Hence, using `pop <- setExtent(pop,studyarea)` I try to change the extent but this leads to a problem as you mentioned before (lonlat to UTM in this case), when I use projectRaster. Sorry, I'm pretty new to working with the Raster package but am learning a lot through trial and error. I really appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: `project` or `projecRaster` will only read what it needs to read, so the size of the input should not matter. Use `terra` for much better performance.

Comment: Thank you Robert, have a great evening!